# looping methods

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, calculator

im trying to write a looping method that goes through the same methods. the number of times that is supposed to loop is determined by how long the string input by the user is. for example, if the string is 1+2-3/4*3+2. the program is supposed to store the first 3 numbers and first 2 operators. then do order of opertations, for this one it would be 1+2-3 = 3-3. then it supposed to get the next operator and the next number from the string. this is the loop that i have so far and it is not looping though the entire string and updating it with the new number and operator

```
public static double solveExpresion(String e) {
    double answer = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < e.length(); i++) {
        String operand1;
        String operand2;
        String operand3;

        operand1 = getOperand(e);
        o1 = Double.parseDouble(operand1);

        operator1 = getOperator(expression);

        operand2 = getOperand(expression);
        o2 = Double.parseDouble(operand2);

        operator2 = getOperator(expression);

        operand3 = getOperand(expression);
        o3 = Double.parseDouble(operand3);

        answer = orderOfOperation(operator1, operator2);

    /*  operator2 = getOperator(expression);

        operand3 = getOperand(expression);
        o3 = Double.parseDouble(operand3);

        answer = orderOfOperation(operator1, operator2);*/
    }

    return (answer);
}
```

note: i am not allowed  to use any sort of arrays.

These are my getOperand and getOperator methods

```
public static String getOperand(String s) {
    s = s.trim();
    String num = "";

    while (s.length() > 0 && s.charAt(0) >= '0' && s.charAt(0) <= '9') {

        num = num + s.charAt(0);
        s = s.substring(1);

    }
    expression = s;

    return (num);
}

public static char getOperator(String s) {

    char r = 0;

    if (s.length() > 0) {

        r = s.charAt(0);
        s = s.substring(1);

    }

    expression = s;
    return (r);
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `getOperand` and `getOperator` method?

Comment: `then do order of opertations, for this one it would be 1+2-3 = 3-3` I don't get what you mean. `1+2-3/4*3+2` would normally be evaluated as `1+2-((3/4)*3)+2`. What definition of "order of operations" are you using? Why are you only reading the first three numbers?

Comment: @MarkByers - My guess is OP's task is to evaluate as if all operators had equal precedence and evaluate them left-to-right.

Comment: public static String getOperand(String s) {
  s = s.trim();
  String num = "";

  while (s.length() > 0 && s.charAt(0) >= '0' && s.charAt(0) <= '9') {

   num = num + s.charAt(0);
   s = s.substring(1);

  }
  expression = s;

  return (num);
 }

 public static char getOperator(String s) {

  char r = 0;

  if (s.length() > 0) {

   r = s.charAt(0);
   s = s.substring(1);

  }

  expression = s;
  return (r);
 }

Comment: that is the algorithm my professor wanted for me to use. read the first three number then user order of operations

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is not complete. Here's an outline (in pseudocode) of how I would do your problem:

```
double answer = getOperand(e);
while (not at end) {
    String operator = getOperator(e);
    double operand2 = getOperand(e);
    answer = orderOfOperation(answer, operator, operand2);
}
return answer;
```

This continually updates `answer` with the next operator/operand. The reason you want to do this is that after you have evaluated part of the expression (say, "1+2"), the next thing in the string (if anything) is an operator and the next operand. There is no left operand to be read; instead you should use the answer so far.

Note also that for the loop to work properly, the first operand must already be consumed (and assigned to `answer`).

Note that your current test for `(not at end)` assumes that every operator and operand is exactly one character long. That's not going to work very well when one of the operands is greater than 9.